# Is this Smart UV Unwrap good topology?

Tags: mesh

I am trying to unwrap a roller model. 
However, I don't know what a good topology would look like.

I think that good UVs should always be rectangular and not curved, is that correct? That would mean hours of moving vertices on my UV map around, wouldn't it?

I am especially unsure about the UV that I have painted a red arrow besides.

I have uploaded the model here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38562

Sorry for the broad range of sub-questions, I am not sure where exactely my problem starts. :-)

Any thoughts on this are very welcome! 
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You could unwrap by hand, marking as seams middle loop and part of loop around wheel. This should give you very basic version of unwrap. You may want to place some small seams across the model to minimize the stretch. Note that if using [texture painting](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/painting.html), the seams' location won't be so important.

Comment: @MrZak Should I unwrap the hi poly model or can I also unwrap a lo poly model and project it back onto the hi poly model?

Comment: If I understand right, you'd like to render lowpoly mesh, baking the normal map from highpoly. So you should not project lowpoly onto the highpoly, rather than use details from highpoly to lowpoly so to reduce polycount of the mesh you're going to render at the same time increasing its details level. In order to bake the normal map, you'll need to unwrap the highpoly. But to assign a texture and render, you'll need to unwrap lowpoly mesh.

Comment: @MrZak Yes, I want to make a lo-poly game model. So you are saying that I need to unwrap both the hi and lo poly model? Sorry, I have not understood it yet.

Comment: Just to rectify - the lowpoly mesh has to be unwrapped, while it's not so important to unwrap a highpoly and you may do that for the sake of completeness.